# Is there any way to set the shorcut name for an Android App?

Tags: android, shortcut

The question says it. I'm developing an app and I deploy it on my phone. However the shortcut is really long. Is there any place where I can set what shortcut name I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in your manifest file :

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/application_icon"
    android:label="@string/your_app_name"
>
```

And in  strings.xml you can set the name:

```
<resources>
    // other strings
    <string name="your_app_name">Name of your App </string>
</resources>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I had to change the name is the app_name of in res/value/strings otherwise the shortcut name would remain the same. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In `manifest` file you can set app name under `application` tag as below.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/application_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
     >
```

then you need to add `app_name` in `strings.xml` inside `res/values/` directory.

like this

```
<string name="app_name">myappname</string>
```

or you can directly set

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/application_icon"
    android:label="myappname"
     >
```

Answer (score 0):

On changing or having the different short label parameter in the launcher intent filter/activity/ application tag in the android manifest file will work for you

```
android:label="short !!"
```

by means you need to write

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/application_icon"
    android:label="@string/application_name"
     >
```

and the application_name should be at Strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="application_name">Short!!</string>
</resources>
```

visit for more

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html